# Processing "RuntimeException: Error opening serial port COM3: Port busy" with no Arduino IDE running

Tags: arduino, processing

I am trying to connect Arduino with my processing program using serial connection, but I get this error when running the sketch.

In the end I want my program to automatically detect on which port is the Arduino connected, but first I wanted to try and communicate with it knowing the port? But I dindn't manage to do it.

Here is my Processing program:

```java
import processing.serial.*;
Serial port;

void setup() {
  size(400,400);
}

void draw() {
    port = new Serial(this, "COM3", 115200);
     println(port);
     if(port.available() > 0) {
       println("yes");
       if(port.readStringUntil('\n').equals("test")) {
          println("y");
          port.write("test_nc");
        }
     }
}
```

And my Arduino program

```cpp
boolean isConnected = false;
boolean lookForPC = true;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  if (lookForPC) {
    while (!isConnected) { //looking for pc serial connection
      Serial.println("test");
      delay(500);
      if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        if (Serial.readStringUntil('\n').equals("test_nc")) {
          Serial.println("ok");
          isConnected = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  Serial.println("done");
}
```

I have read that the problem may come from the arduino IDE listening to the Serial port at the same time but when Processing is the only program running I get the same error.

I've tried rebooting my pc and changing USB port for my Arduino, but I always get this error even when Arduino is not running.

Thank you.

Comment: port = new Serial(this, "COM3", 115200); needs to be in setup(); but code will ultimately fail with null pointer exception.  Suggest changing code similar to example shown in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain that I understand what you are trying to do.  The code that you posted makes no sense to me.  Perhaps explain in words what you want to accomplish.  In the meantime, please see if you can run this simple demo (substitute com port for your system).  To avoid the 'busy' error I first uploaded the Arduino code and then closed the editor and switched to Processing. I believe that using a serialEvent() function is preferable to using draw() for serial events.

**Processing code:**

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial port;
String inStr;  // Input string from serial port

void setup() {
  surface.setVisible(false);
  printArray(Serial.list());
  port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[3], 9600);
}

void draw() {
}

void serialEvent(Serial p) {
  inStr = p.readStringUntil('\n');
  if (inStr != null) {
    inStr = trim(inStr);
    println(inStr);
  }
}
```

**Arduino code:**

```
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Processing is great.");
}
```

Comment: Nice answer (+1). FWIW, The question reminds me a bit of the old school [Serial Call Reponse example](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/communication/SerialCallResponse) but with slightly more complicated call/response logic. If @Kduck can clarify the intentions/overall goal that would help a lot. (minor, but `port.bufferUntil('\n')` could be used in `setup()` then simply `p.readString()` in `serialEvent` and ideally setting up the port should be in a try/catch to handle port not found/port busy/etc. errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code works fine but I was trying to automatically detect on whiwh port was the arduino connected. In order to do that I need my `port = new Serial(...)` to be in the draw() not in setup(). I will try and understand more about why my code didn't work based on yours.

Comment: On a Mac the port will not show up in the Serial.list() if it is not connected.  If you want to know if it is connected to an Arduino one option would be to send a character to Arduino and immediately Serial.println() it back to Processing.  If it comes back to Processing then Arduino is connected.  If it doesn't come back to Processing then the Arduino is not connected.